# Navigation Bar gets visible again after open and close keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, navigationbar

private int currentApiVersion;

```
private void hideNavigationBar() {
    currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    // This work only for android 4.4+
    if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

        // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
        // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
        // show up and won't hide
        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView
                .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

i called hideNavigationBar method from onCreate, but its not work for me. when i open keybard on clicking EditText and then close keyboard, but navigation bar not get invisible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide navigation bar when closing the keyboard. Refer below code for this. It will help you

```
final View activityRootView = ((ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        private final int DefaultKeyboardDP = 100;
        private final int EstimatedKeyboardDP = DefaultKeyboardDP + (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? 48 : 0);
        private final Rect r = new Rect();
        private boolean wasOpened;
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Convert the dp to pixels.
            int estimatedKeyboardHeight = (int) TypedValue
                    .applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, EstimatedKeyboardDP, activityRootView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            // Conclude whether the keyboard is shown or not.
            activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
            boolean isShown = heightDiff >= estimatedKeyboardHeight;
            if (isShown == wasOpened) {
                Log.d("Keyboard state", "Ignoring global layout change...");
                return;
            }
            wasOpened = isShown;
            if (isShown) {
                // Show keyborad
            } else {
                // Hide keyboard 
            }
        }
    });
```